# Removing the head node of my linked list? C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have this somewhat unconventionally coded linked list and am trying to remove the head of it.

This is a hashtable, so it's an array of linked list

```
myStruct *pointer = HashTable[i];
```

1->2->3->NULL

How can I delete the 1 and make 2 the head of the list?
I've tried pointer = pointer->next but when I re-display the table, it still is printing 1->2->3->NULL, not 2->3->NULL.

Comment: I'm not even so much worried about freeing it from memory, but more-so just relinking the head of the list.

Comment: Please, provide more code and use `code` tags to improve readability.

Comment: My crystal ball says you passed the head pointer to a function by value. And changed the value of head pointer in that function and now wonder why outside that function the head still points to the previous head.

Comment: Why does nobody ever use `<list>`? Writing this correctly from scratch is hard, and a total waste of time.

Comment: I hope the reason is homework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend the image I made for you. I think it is safer than saying something like :

```
node *temp = head

head =head->next 

delete temp
```

Because depending on how you handle your pointers, you could run the risk of deleting your whole list. Doing it this way, you will lose the head and make sure you have the rest of the list. But do what you like! man - try things out.
[image]

Comment: Excellent response. Pictures = +1 for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
void changethehead(node*&head) {
    node *tobedeleted = head;
    head = head->next;   // head is the next element
    delete tobedeleted; // delete the old head
}
```